# Validation Error in APS 2.0 Package "Upsell Demo Project" on Sandbox

Tags: aps

After i figured out how to build the Demo Project "`Upsell Management`" ([project](https://doc.apsstandard.org/pa/pa-demo-projects/upsell/)), i'm struggling now with the installation in the `sandbox`.

I'm running a `sandbox` with `POA 5.5-5562_update06-824` and every time i try to install it i get a Status "`Validation Error`":

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le3WQ.png

So, is there a log file or anything to find out what is the error behind that?

Answer (score 0):

'Validation error' means that package import task has failed, more details on this can be found in Operations->Tasks

If you see a validation error that you did not see while running apsbuild/apslint tool this means that either you or POA have an older version of apstools.

The best way is redeploy sandbox to latest POA version and update APS tools on your build machine (http://doc.apsstandard.org/2.1/tools/cli-tools/#cli-tools)